# Prawn How can I fill a form Field using Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, prawn

I'm using the `Prawn Gem 0.12.0` in a `rails 3.0` application.

My document shows up fine with:

```
class TemplatePdf < Prawn::Document
def initialize

filename= "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/pdfs/RMA_Formular.pdf"
        super(:template => filename)
        text_box "2005-xxxx1055", :at=>[40,472]
        text_box "#{current_user.email}", :at =>[280, 472]
        text_box ...
...
end
```

The text_box prefills several Form Fields of the RMA-form.

I want to use the field names of the pdf's form fields instead of positioning them manually using `text_box "xxx", :at=>[x, y]`.

So is there a way to send for example the user's email to the email form field?

I would expect some code like

```
template.fields[:email] => current_user.email
```

which would fill the pdf's form field as expected and save me from hardcoding absolute positions for each template design.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this one, but I noticed from the examples that `:at => [x, y]` is a **mandatory option** and used to position an element **exactly** at `(x, y)` position of the document.

If you don't want to position exactly at `(x,y)` position, you can use the `text` method as follows

```
text "Some string"
move_down 20
text "Some other string"
```

An alternate option would be you can keep these position values for each field in a yml file and reuse in instead of hardcoding within the code.

Comment: I think you missunderstood. the template might change, and so might change the positions of for example the email field, but there will still be an email field. If i code with :at=>[x, y] I have to reprogramm the positions on every change of the template.

Comment: Is there a way to read an existing PDF and find where the existing fields are progrmaatically.